# How do I map path components into query parameters using mod_rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, vanity-url, pretty-urls

How would I change this:
http://www.mattvisk.com/?page=portfolio&item=rae

To this:
http://www.mattvisk.com/portfolio/rae

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(images/|css/|js/)
RewriteRule . - [S=2]

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_\-\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_\-\.]+)/([a-z0-9_\-\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&item=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Make sure mod_rewrite is enable

**edit:** I added the dot, poolie had a good point there.

The [S] flag is used to skip rules that you don't want to run. This can be thought of as a goto statement in your rewrite ruleset. In the following example, we only want to run the RewriteRule if the requested URI doesn't correspond with an actual file.

Comment: I think you need a `/` at the start of the regexps, after the carat?  Also, I'd be inclined to match just `[^/]+` so that it doesn't break when someone puts a dot in the portfolio name, etc.

Comment: You can add `/` at the start but I personally prefer to use the `RewriteBase /`. So if you need to add rules, it's easier. I agree with the second part, although I don't like having characters other than `-`, `_`, `.` in the URL.

Comment: Interesting.  I didn't think that was exactly what it was meant for, but I guess it works...

Comment: It broke my style sheet. What changes should I be making in my basic html file pertaining to file & img paths and links.

Comment: @MattVisk you have the list of files/folder (css, images etc...)?